# Java: Why is my synchronized output still so random

Tags: java, synchronization

So I'm practicing with synchronization for the first time. I'm trying to implement a practice concept that was described in general on the Oracle Java Concurrency tutorial.

The idea is to have a special Counter object, with methods to increment, decrement, and show value. My goal was to get it run by two different threads to generate random conflicts, and to then solve those conflicts through synchronization. So far I feel like the second part is not working, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The code I'm pasting below is simple. There are two threads, with two runnables. Each runnable:

1) contains a reference to the same, single Counter object
2) runs a loop five times
3) sleeps for 1 second each time the loop runs
4) prints the current value of the Counter.

The only difference between MyRunnable1 & MyRunnable2 is that the first one increments the counter, and the second one decrements the counter.

Obviously when I ran it without synchronized methods it produced random results. But even after I synchronized the methods, the results were still apparently random.

SAMPLE RESULTS 1:
1
0
1
0
1
0
-1
0
1
0

SAMPLE RESULTS 2:
-1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
-1
0

WHAT I THINK IT SHOULD BE: It should consistently go 1 0 1 0 1 0 etc etc until all the loops are finished. If I'm wrong there, if it's the way I'm thinking about thread behavior, please point that out.

Below is my code. All thoughts/advice appreciated. This is my first attempt at using synchronization in any way, I want to get it down because it's such an important concept.

```
public class CounterSync {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Counter c = new Counter();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable1(c));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable2(c));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public static class Counter{
        private int c = 0;

        public synchronized void increment(){
            c++;
        }

        public synchronized void decrement(){
            c--;
        }

        public synchronized int value(){
            return c;
        }
    }

    public static class MyRunnable1 implements Runnable{
        private Counter c;

        public MyRunnable1(Counter c){
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){

            try{
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    c.increment();
                    System.out.println(c.value());
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static class MyRunnable2 implements Runnable{
        private Counter c;

        public MyRunnable2(Counter c){
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    c.decrement();
                    System.out.println(c.value());
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Your code is synchronized but not atomic, and also the exact order (and timing) of your threads is up to the system scheduler and not under your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronization does not mean ordering. Perhaps the word 'synchronization' is misleading. In your case, when one has synchronized methods, it means that at a given instant maximum one thread can be running a *synchronized* method on the object in question.

You can read 'synchronized' as 'one at a time'.

Whenever you have more than one thread running, how much each thread will progress is decided by the system. Further, `Thread.sleep` is guaranteed to sleep *at least* for the given interval, but *not* exact. The two facts combined will give you the random ordering.

Comment: Your answer is close but slightly wrong and confusing. Perhaps you meant one thread or one synchronized method instead of one method... Non-synchronized methods could be running on other threads at the same time as a synchronized method is running on a particular thread.

Comment: @doogabides Actually I think what I said is correct. When an object has synchronized methods, then on a given object only one thread can be running a synchronized method. So if there are two synchronized methods m1 and m2 on an object o, and one thread tries m1 while the other is in m2, the first one will have to wait.

Comment: But yes, I will add the word _synchronized_ to the last line of first para.

Comment: You should also point out that synchronization controls visibility in addition to "one at a time" behavior.  Without some form of synchronization (volatile, final, etc.) [writes to a field are not guaranteed to be visible to another thread.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3)  Tricky, but very important to understand.

Comment: @markspace As a comment it's too short to understand it. Can you add it as an answer and elaborate a bit?

Comment: From what I recall from researching the Java Memory Model, synchronization does provide sequential ordering between a release and subsequent aquire on a lock. Click on the link @markspace supplied and scroll down to Synchronization Order: "*Synchronization actions induce the synchronized-with relation on an unlock action on monitor m and all subsequent lock actions on m*"

Comment: (Continued) Scrolling down to Happens Before: "*Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.*" which lists "*If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).*" He's not accounting for when he's synchronizing; his `Thread.sleep` isn't accounted for when synchronizing, which can throw it off. Please correct me if I'm wrong.